# Custom events versus callbacks in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, dom-events

I'm new to ReactJS and I'm trying to figure out how to store and manipulate global state. For example, I'm writing an editor app that has some global state: selected color/background, active tool, current selection, etc.

I'm thinking about having a root interface component to store this information, and I'm ok with explicitly passing the state around using properties. I guess the idiomatic way for a children component to change global state is calling a callback received from the parent - personally I find this a bit annoying.

Instead, I'm firing custom events at the children and setting listeners on the parent. So far it is working really well, but I looked at a [lot of sample code](https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react) and never saw people using this pattern.

Is there any practical consequences I should consider?

Comment: It can get slow if you have to traverse through a ton of components and update the props but it all comes down to personal preference and what you like doing.

Comment: Are you using Flux at all? What you're doing is a highly short-circuited version of Flux. Except your events would be actions, your listeners would be stores listening to the dispatcher, and your state would be in a store listened to by your root view.

Comment: @tom thanks for the tip, I have no clue about Flux (thought it was a server thing), will take a look - probably I'm trying to reinvent it. If there is a dispatcher involved I guess it enqueue events; this would boost performance and make it easier to debug (event driven architectures can be a pain).

Comment: @tom Now that I have read more about Flux, I'm really looking for alternatives. One could think the main point behind Flux is to make React feel as complicated as Angular. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flux is great for manipulating global state because the Stores are globally accessible. Globals are known to be bad, but the way you interact with the Stores is through Actions. Actions make the state predictable and localized. So even though the state storage itself is global, Actions make the state interactions very *local*. At work we tend to do both reading & writing through Actions, so every state change is an "event" that leads to easily programmable behavior.

I really wouldn't compare Flux to Angular as their principles and flows are entirely different. Suggest you try Reflux.